# how do I get rid of the ldap_connect() error

Tags: php, windows

- Windows Server 2016 64 bit (Fully Updated)
- WAMP/3.0.6 (Win32)
- Apache/2.4.9 (Win32)
- PHP/7.2.6 (Win32)

**Error 1 : Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function ldap_connect()**

I've been sitting with this error now for a while and I don't seem to get it sorted. Nothing I do seems to have any impact on this error. I also can't seem to find any source of these DLL files. My guess is that the DLL fails to load , because it's somehow not compatible with 7.2.6

**What I have tried :**

0.) Enabled extension in php.ini using the correct php.ini file

1.) Copied *libeay32.dll,ssleay32.dll,php_ldap.dll,libsasl.dll* into *C:\Windows\system*, *\apache2.4.9\bin*

Everything else works fine. I can run phpinfo() and I have a few other sites on there that open up fine. My error log file is as follows :

```
[16-Jun-2018 20:17:30 UTC] PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'php_curl.dll' (tried: d:/wamp/bin/php/php7.2.6/ext/php_curl.dll (The specified module could not be found.), d:/wamp/bin/php/php7.2.6/ext/php_php_curl.dll.dll (The specified module could not be found.)) in Unknown on line 0
[16-Jun-2018 20:17:30 UTC] PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'php_ldap.dll' (tried: d:/wamp/bin/php/php7.2.6/ext/php_ldap.dll (The specified module could not be found.), d:/wamp/bin/php/php7.2.6/ext/php_php_ldap.dll.dll (The specified module could not be found.)) in Unknown on line 0
[16-Jun-2018 20:17:30 UTC] PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'php_openssl.dll' (tried: d:/wamp/bin/php/php7.2.6/ext/php_openssl.dll (The specified module could not be found.), d:/wamp/bin/php/php7.2.6/ext/php_php_openssl.dll.dll (The specified module could not be found.)) in Unknown on line 0
[16-Jun-2018 20:17:30 UTC] PHP Deprecated:  Directive 'track_errors' is deprecated in Unknown on line 0
```

How can I get rid of the ldap error ?

Comment: You should start by addressing the `PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library` errors. Since `php_ldap.dll` is one of the modules that can't be found your ldap error will probably be resolved once you find the missing modules.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up downloading and installing a new version of WAMP which included PHP 7.2.4. I then enabled the **extension=php_ldap.dll**. I did not need to copy any other files

Answer (score 0):

I run into the same problem, but using only apache and php (not xampp or wampp or other pre installed packages). To solve my problem I needed to set the php path on the PATH environment variable of the windows server (ie adding C:\PHP). It solved the problem.